# Flutter/Dart group custom list of places by category field

Tags: flutter, dart, group

I have following (custom) list of Places.

```
Place(
      id: 'e74ab0ae20f95d6a78a92c30102badf9',
      name: 'Sonnenuhr',
      latitude: 47.9692658,
      longitude: 13.1067706,
      address: 'Weyerbucht 2, 5163 Mattsee',
      isSelling: false,
      category: 'tourist_attraction',
    ),
    Place(
      id: '5c7d5fe41d68b3e9b5846790b4b91dde',
      name: 'Wagnerhäusl',
      latitude: 47.969763,
      longitude: 13.0787413,
      address: 'Hauptstraße, 5164 Seeham',
      isSelling: false,
      category: 'tourist_attraction',
    ),
    Place(
      id: 'ddae22feda7bf3bc27a82fa697134a38',
      name: 'Freilichtmuseum Kugelmühle',
      latitude: 47.9537128,
      longitude: 13.0606178,
      address: '5164 Seeham',
      isSelling: false,
      category: 'museum',
    ),
    Place(
      id: '72d7a20a288371c64f3cd13e7b0c9434',
      name: 'Hochseilpark Seeham',
      latitude: 47.9583366,
      longitude: 13.0651359,
      address: 'Tobelmühlstraße 25, 5164 Seeham',
      isSelling: false,
      category: 'amusement_park',
    )
```

My goal is, that I group it by the field "category". I load it into my screen like so:

```
final placesData = Provider.of<Places>(context); 
final places = placesData.interestingPlaces;
```

I output it in a ListView and what I tried so far to group it, was:

```
var newList = groupBy(places, (Map obj) => obj['category']);
```

This gives me: "The argument type 'dynamic Function(Map<dynamic, dynamic>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(Place)'"

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the function you're passing to `groupBy` is expecting the wrong parameter type (`Map` instead of `Place`).

Try `var newList = groupBy(places, (Place place) => place.category);`, assuming a getter for `category` exists.